# Migrating to Bounded Context

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I currently have a Web API project which currently has all the system processing in the same solution. I'm breaking this out into separate solutions so that they can be ran independently (e.g. an Azure WebJob) as I don't want to have to redploy the Web project if something in the backend has changed.

My issue with this is that even though I have separated the logic they are tied together by a single context so that if I make a change in one I will have to redeploy all as the migrations won't match up.

So that's why I've been looking at Bounded Context and DDD. I'm looking at how to break this up but having trouble understanding how relationships work.

A lot of the site is administrative (i.e. creating entities, no actual processing) so was going to split contexts around this e.g.:

1. A user adds and maintains currency conversion rates (this is two entities in 
   total).
2. A user adds and maintains details on how to process payments (note that is is not processing payments, it only holds information about paypal account details etc).

So I was splitting the context's up by this, does this sound reasonable to start with (there are a lot more like this such as tax bands, charge structures etc)?

If this is the way to go, how do I handle relationships between those two contexts? As an example:

1. A payment method requires a link to an 'active' currency conversion. I understand I can just have this as an Id, but I need to check it's state so need access to the model.
2. A currency conversion can only be set to 'Inactive' if there are no payment methods currently using it. Again this needs access to the other model.

So logically the models need access to each other, how would this be included in the context? Can I add navigation properties to a model in a different context? Or should I add it as a separate `DbSet` and possibly map using a view?

Thanks

Comment: Rules across bounded contexts can only be made eventually consistent. Usually, every context would have it's own copy of the data it needs to make decisions and would keep it up to date through various mechanisms (e.g. messaging). If your bounded contexts are sharing a lot of state then perhaps they shouldn't be split. "if there are no payment methods currently using it" This looks like a made-up rule. Does it really matter to the business that a currency got deactivated at the same exact moment as a payment using it got processed?

Comment: The example in the question sounds like a single bounded context to me.  In several DDD books, they tend to show the modelling of the bounded contexts as being separate departments in a single organisation.  Where both departments might both use the term 'Client', but they might both have different interests in the client's details.  I.e. Dispatch might only be interested in the client's address, whereas Sales might only be interested in the client's telephone number and birthday.

Comment: Following on, if you imagine a Dispatch system that has the client's birthday displayed everywhere, it is polluting the Dispatch system with concerns from the Sales team.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips I think that's a factor in me not understanding this fully - having duplicate data. I've always had the thought that data shouldn't be redundant but in your example there would be duplicate data in for a client in the Sales and Dispatch Client tables. So we would realistically be storing twice as many rows, but within the context of the department?

Comment: @ADringer it's usually very hard to convert an existing data-centric design to a DDD application-centric design.  If you're talking 'tables', then you're thinking about designing the system from the database upwards, which is pretty much the opposite of DDD.  Ideally your bounded contexts would be separate systems that know how they relate to each other (upstream, downstream, etc.), so each bounded context would have a separate persistence store (if required).

Answer (score 0):

> So I was splitting the context's up by this, does this sound
>   reasonable to start with (there are a lot more like this such as tax
>   bands, charge structures etc)?

- "So that they can be ran and deployed independently" may not be a sufficient heuristic to tell when you should split Bounded Contexts. This addresses one aspect of the solution space, but if you haven't looked well enough at the problem space, you'll suffer from a misalignment between BC's and subdomains that can cause a lot of friction. You might end up always deploying a cluster of seemingly unrelated "independently deployable units" together because you didn't realize they talk about the same thing.

  Identifying subdomains is the product of *distillating* your business - separating the big functional areas and defining which parts are your core domain and which are ancillary activities. Each subdomain has its own specific semantics (Ubiquitous Language). In your case, as has been pointed out in the comments, `Currency Conversion` and `Payment Methods` might well be part of the same subdomain (Payment?). It does not automatically mean that they should also be in the same BC but it might be a [good idea](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2013/04/29/sub-domains-and-bounded-contexts-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) to keep subdomains aligned 1-to-1 with BC's, as additional BC's come at a cost.

  Back to deployability, even if it can be one beneficial effect of Bounded Contexts, they are not always so easily translatable in terms of independent units of deployment. Context mapping patterns (Shared Kernel, Customer Supplier, etc.) and BC communication in general can lead to a model, and therefore a part of a codebase, being shared by multiple BC's. Code and API synchronization issues arise that can question a simplistic "deployable free electron" view.
- Just because you're using the Bounded Context approach doesn't mean you have to use DDD's tactical patterns (Aggregate Root, invariants, etc.) inside each BC. Using them should be an educated decision to trade solution space complexity off for problem space manageability. If "Currency Conversion can only be set to inactive..." is the only rule pertaining to payment method and currency management in your business, it might not be worth the bother to give that Bounded Context a full-fledged rich domain model. CRUD could be better suited there.